# Symfony 3.4 [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException] Command

Tags: console, command, symfony-3.4

(The text you have in front of you comes from an online translator).

Context: Develop a Symfony command to retrieve in database the addresses of my localization table that do not have GPS coordinates, (the localizations whose fields latitude and longitude are null). Find the GPS coordinates corresponding to the address via Google API (google geocoding) and then insert the coordinates in database.

Code files :

LocationCommand.php

```
 <?php

 namespace Keosu\DataModel\LocationModelBundle\Command;

 use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand;
 use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
 use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
 use Keosu\DataModel\LocationModelBundle\Utils\LocationManager;



class LocationCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{

private $locationManager;

public function __construct(LocationManager $locationManager)
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->locationManager = $locationManager;
}

protected function configure()
{
    $this
        ->setName('keosu:coordinated')
        ->setDescription('Populate table location with google coordinated , if the field long and lat are empty')
        ->setHelp('For call this command enter app/console Keosu:coordinated ')
    ;
}

protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $apiUrl = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?";
    $apiKey = $this->getContainer()->getParameter('google_api_key');

    //My collection of location
    $locations = $this->locationManager->findAll();

    foreach ($locations as $location)
    {
        if ($location->getLat() == null  && $location->getLng() == null)
        {
            $address = $location->getAddress();
            $address .= ',' . $location->getPostalCode();

            $urlAddress = preg_replace('/\s+/', '+', $address);
            $geolocUrl = $apiUrl.'address='.$urlAddress.'&key='.$apiKey;

            //Query to send for Geocoding API
            $query = sprintf($geolocUrl,urlencode(utf8_encode($address)));
            $result = json_decode(file_get_contents($query));
            $json = $result->results[0];

            $address->setLat($json->geometry->location->lat);
            $address->setLng($json->geometry->location->lng);
            $em->persist($address);
            $em->flush();

        }
    }


}

}
```

The service I use for my command : LocationManager.php

```
 <?php

namespace Keosu\DataModel\LocationModelBundle\Utils;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

class LocationManager
{
private $em;

public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
{
    $this->em = $em;
}

public function findAll()
{
    //Find all location

    return $this->em->getRepository('LocationModelBundle:Location')->findAll();


}


}
```

The problem: When in the console I enter "app/console keosu:coordinated" to start my command, the console displays this error:

```
[Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]
Command "keosu:coordinated" is not defined.
Did you mean this?

keosu:export
```

keosu: export is a command that is in another directory. The command is in this directory (Keosu/CoreBundle/Command/ExportCommand.php).

I did check the namespace yet the error persists. I do not even know if my code will process my request, since the command does not start.

Here is the architecture of the application.

[image: Architecture of the application]

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.